# How to fix enum error while using zeep in python to access API

Tags: python, api, serialization, soap, zeep

I am using python 3.6 and zeep to access the following [api](http://www.alsoenergy.com/WebAPI/WebAPI.svc?singleWsdl).

I have set up the client and can get logged in and get some things to work.  But this one call won't work and I can't figure out why.

```
AEclient = zeep.Client(wsdl=AEwsdl, wsse=UsernameToken(AE_username, AE_password), settings = AEsettings)

data = AEclient.service.GetBinData(sessionID = AESessionID, fromLocal = '2/1/2020', toLocal = '2/5/2020', binSize = 15, Fields = {'DataField': [{'FieldName': 'KWHnet', 'Function': '0', 'HID': '10000'}, {'HID': '10000', 'FieldName': 'KW', 'Function': '0'}]})
```

"I get the following error: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter alsoenergy_ns:binSize. The InnerException message was 'Invalid enum value '15' cannot be deserialized into type 'AlsoEnergyAPI.Data.BinSizes'. Ensure that the necessary enum values are present and are marked with EnumMemberAttribute attribute if the type has DataContractAttribute attribute.'.  Please see InnerException for more details."

I have tried changing the binSize to be other apparent options like 0, 60, etc.  I have tried using int(15), '15', 'Bin15Min', etc. to no avail.

There are two variables the seem to be 'enumerated'; Function and binSize.  If i remove these from the command, it seems to process with the defaults.  I just can't seem to state something that works with the enumeration values?

Any suggestions or next things to try?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the secret was but when I finally used binSize = 'Bin15Min' and 'function': 'Avg' it worked.  I guess the integer placeholders for these don't work but the full string version does.

```
data = AEclient.service.GetBinData(sessionID = AESessionID, fromLocal = '2/1/2020', toLocal = '2/5/2020', binSize = 'Bin15Min', Fields = {'DataField': [{'FieldName': 'KWHnet', 'Function': 'Avg', 'HID': '10000'}]})
```